# Angular 2 - Declare Empty Model with interface

Tags: angular

when i use interfaces in model im getting this typescript error

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'address'.

My Model

```
export class student {
        constructor(
            public admission_no: string,
            public name: string,
            public dob: string,
            public nationality: string,
            public gender: string,
            public blood_group: string,
            public present_add: address,
            public permanent_add: address,
            public religion: string,
            public caste: string,
            public finacial_status: string,
            public mobile_no: string,
            public home_no: string,
            public email: string,
            public identical_mark1: string,
            public identical_mark2: string,
            public accadamic_year: string,
            public school: string,
            public std: string,
            public division: string,
            public stream: string,
            public father: parentDetails,
            public mother: parentDetails,
            public doc:doc[],
            public same_address:any,
            public photo?: string,
            public adhar_no?: string,
            public hobbies?: string,
            public local_guardian?: parentDetails,
            public sibilings?: string,
            public prev_school?: school,
        ) { }
    }
    export interface address {
        house_name: string;
        street: string;
        dist: string;
        state: string;
        country: string;
        pincode: string;
    }
    export interface parentDetails {
        name: string;
        adhar_no: string;
        mobile_no: string;
        email: string;
        occupation: string;
        education: string;
        office_add: string;
        pan_no: string;
        income_tax_pays: string;
    }
    export interface school {
        school_name: String;
        board: String;
        medium: String;
        stream: String;
        standard: String;
        from_date: String;
        to_date: String;
        persentage: String;
        result: String;
        add: String;
        city: String;
        state: String;
        country: String;
        contact_no: String;
        email: String;
    }
    export interface doc{
        id:string;
        name:string;
        filename:string;
    }
```

this is how i declare model on component

```
 student = new student('','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',[''],'');
```

is it right way to declare an model? or what is wrong in my code??

Comment: Why do you think, assigning a string to a parameter of type `address` should work?

Comment: my knowledge in angular 2 is very limited. and i  got confused :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 student = new student('','','','','','',null,null,'','','','','','','','','','',null,'','','','',[''],'');
```

or

```
 student = new student('','','','','','',{},{},'','','','','','','','','','',{},'','','','',[''],'');
```

similar for other parameters, that are not of type `string`.

Comment: This is getting another : error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'address'.  Property 'house_name' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: *this code is working :* student = new student('','','','','','',{house_name:null,street:null,dist:null,state:null,country:null,pincode:null},{house_name:null,street:null,dist:null,state:null,country:null,pincode:null},'','','','','','','','','','','','','',{name:null,adhar_no:null,mobile_no:null,email:null,occupation:null,education:null,office_add:null,pan_no:null,income_tax_pays:null},{name:null,adhar_no:null,mobile_no:null,email:null,occupation:null,education:null,office_add:null,pan_no:null,income_tax_pays:null},[{id:null,name:null,filename:null}],'');

Comment: I missed the scrollbar in your code and didn't see the interface declarations. Glad to see you figured it out.